# Powersehll script to execute an exe with multiple arguments and gets the argument information from excel

Tags: powershell

I'm newbie to the powershell script world, I need a powershell script to call an executable that has five arguments.

In the command prompt I execute the exe like below and its for a single application. Now I want to automate this for multiple applications. The application information (application name, version, env, filepath, reportname"  stored in excel spread sheet.

Executer.exe --ApplicationName='Application1' --Version='20.2.1 -Env="" --filpath="C:\path" -reportname="Report.pdf" --> This is for single application.

The script should execute the exe with arguments from the excel spread sheet and run for application rows available in the spread sheet.

I tried different options nothing is working out. please help.

Comment: If you've "tried different options" post what you think is the one that's closest to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds too simple, but did u try this?

```
$path = C:\path\executer.exe
&$path --ApplicationName='Application1' --Version='20.2.1 -Env="" --filpath="C:\path" -reportname="Report.pdf"
```

If that works you could substitute single parameters with variables from the excelsheet.

Comment: Nope. It didn't work. I get the below error message. Just to be clear, I need to get the arguments from the spreadsheet every time it executes.                                                               The string starting:
At C:\executiondir\execution.ps1:2 char:261
+ &$path --ApplicationName="Application1" --Version="20.2.1" -env="" --filepath="C:\Temp\bin" -r="report <<<< "
is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\executiondir\execution.ps1:3 char:1
+  <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (
:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Import-Csv c:\path\config.csv |
foreach {
 $app =$_.application
 $version = $_.version
 $env = $_.env
 $filepath = $_.path
 $reportname = $_.rep
 
 Start-Process cmd.exe /c c:\path\executer.exe -a $_.application -v $_.version -env "`"`"" -filepath $_.path -r $_.rep
 
}

I'm trying to execute executer.exe with arugments in seperate command prompts. Its not working. 
Any ideas? I really appreciate your help.